# How to run the build inside docker container in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

In my application I have a `build` script in `package.json`.

The `build` makes `dist` folder and inside I have my application.

I set Jenkins master and Jenkins agent as say in [boxboat setup jenkins with docker](https://github.com/boxboat/jenkins-demo/blob/develop/docs/part1-jenkins-setup.md) and watch the [video in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkGXAPj8wSI).

But now after I did this, I don't think my bash commands running inside a container.

I want to `clone` the repo and run `npm i` and `npm run build` - **inside the docker container**.

How I modify this configuration to able to do that?

```
throttle(['throttleDocker']) {
  node('docker') {
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper']) {
      try{
        stage('Build') {
          checkout scm
          sh '''
            echo "in Setup"
            docker ps -a
            echo "after docker"
            # ./ci/docker-down.sh
            # ./ci/docker-up.sh
          '''
        }
        stage('Test'){
          parallel (
            "unit": {
              sh '''
                echo "in unit"
               # ./ci/test/unit.sh
              '''
            },
            "functional": {
              sh '''
                echo "in functional"
               # ./ci/test/functional.sh
              '''
            }
          )
        }
        stage('Capacity Test') {
          sh '''
            echo "in Capacity Test"
           # ./ci/test/stress.sh
          '''
        }
      }
      finally {
        stage('Cleanup') {
          sh '''
            echo "in Cleanup"
            # ./ci/docker-down.sh
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to this codes but they don't work. I also add agent after `try`.

```
 stage('Build') {
        agent {
            docker {
              label 'docker'
              image 'node:latest'
            }
          }
         steps {
           checkout scm
           sh 'node -v'
         }
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below scripted pipeline

```
node {

    docker.image('yourimage').inside {
        stage('Build'){
            sh 'echo "Build stage inside container"'
        }
        stage('Test'){
            sh 'echo "Test Stage inside container"'
        }
    }
}
```